# Combining/ Merging all TMaps into a single table

Tags: talend

I have the following [talend job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g6ks.png) where each is an API call to get the currency exchange rate. 
The fields within each Tmap are:
- FrommCurr
- ToCurr (Each Tmap has a hardcoded string value "EUR", "USD", "CAD")
- Date
- DateTime

I would like to combine all of these into a single table before inserting. what is the object that will let me combine them? Or should I insert each single TMap into the database? The database, I will be inserting into is MSSQL.

Comment: What do you mean by table here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long As all  the final tMap components produce  exactly the same schema , you can join the output into a single stream of rows with tUnite .